# php добавляет строки из-за тегов при экспорте в excel

Tags: php

В файле вывожу таблицу с данными и экспорт в excel таким способом:

```
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=products.xls");  
  header("Pragma: no-cache");  
  header("Expires: 0");
```

В цикле вывожу данные в ячейку. Если в ячейке есть `html` или `<br>` то в excel данные в нескольких строках получаются.

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $price."<br>"; ?></td> // уже не 1, а 2 строки будет к примеру.
</tr>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как добавить перенос в ячейке между текстом, чтоб строки в excel не добавлялись? \n выводит как текст.
2. Как сделать чтобы из-за разных <тегов> не добавлялись строки?

Comment: например, начать с того, чтобы не пытаться построить эксель файл в виде html документа. Есть библиотеки для генерации нормальных файлов, их и используйте.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: спс, сделал через PhpSpreadsheet, там тоже можно html в эксель записать и все норм заносит.